# Patrón para definir fechas en las clases de utilería

Tags: java, datetime, date

Tengo la típica clase de utilería con atributos `static final` modo:

```
public class AppConstants {

    // CONSTANTES DE LA APLICACION

    /** Valor de toneladas por cada lote */
    public static final double TONELADAS_LOTES_MULTIPLICADOR = 50;
    /** Pattern para generar el numero de fijacion */
    public static final String FIJACION_NUMBER_PATTERN = "/F";
    /** Pattern para generar el numero de la media */
    public static final String MEDIA_NUMBER_PATTERN = "/M";

    // mas...
}
```

Ahora se me pide que la fecha mínima para ciertos casos sea el 1 de Enero de 2014. Cual seria la manera correcta de centralizarlo sin usar librerias externas? El objetivo es usarlo con la funcion [`Date.before()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)).

Dado que el constructor [`Date(int, int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(int,%20int,%20int)) esta deprecated no puedo (ni quiero) hacer:

```
public static final Date MIN_VALID_DATE = new Date(1,1,2014);
```

He llegado a esta solucion en 2 partes:

```
public class AppConstants {

    // otros campos

    // El String "01/01/2014" se recoge de la BBDD.
    public static final Date MIN_VALID_DATE = DateUtils.getMinimumDate("01/01/2014"); 
}
```

Y se rellena asi:

```
public class DateUtils {

    // otras utilidades para fechas

    public static Date getMinimumDate(String date) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        try {
            return sdf.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Pero la verdad es que no me parece lo más elegante del mundo:

- **¿Alguien conoce algún patrón aplicable para estos casos?.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si trabajas sobre Java 8, lo mejor sería utilizar la clase [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) puesto que es inmutable. La sintaxis sería de esta manera:

```
public static final LocalDate MIN_VALID_DATE = LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 1);
```

Si no trabajas con Java 8, entonces la alternativa que usas es la única que tienes. Si quieres asegurar que no pueden modificar ese valor, puesto que `java.util.Date` es mutable (!), lo mejor sería almacenar el resultado de `Date#getTime` como constante:

```
public static final long MIN_VALID_DATE_VALUE = DateUtils.getMinimumDate("01/01/2014").getTime();
```

Y luego utilizarlo en tus comparaciones/validaciones de esta manera:

```
new Date(MIN_VALID_DATE_VALUE).before(...)
```

No te preocupes por la creación de este objeto múltiples veces. Las JVMs actuales están más que preparadas para optimizar este tipo de escenarios.

Comment: uhm, buena opcion el tema `long`... he hecho pruebas y es cierto que si, por ejemplo hago `MIN_VALID_DATE.setTime(0);` se cambia la fecha... aunque no es una opción logica dentro de la app, es una posibilidad a tener en cuenta... vamos a ver si hay alguna propuesta más con un patrón diferente.

Comment: @JordiCastilla puede que no, pero alguien puede hacer lo siguiente: `Date fechaMinima = MIN_VALID_DATE; /* ... */ fechaMinima.setTime(<cualquier cosa>);` y bam! destrucción de tu variable y generando bugs de miles de pesetas.

Comment: Hostia Luiggi, ¿miles de pesetas? Me has hecho reir con ganas!!!  